# How can I stop apt-get from asking about using minor amounts of additional disk space that will be used?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, configuration, ux

I know that I can use parameters (with aliases or `apt.conf` I can even make it permanent) to skip this steep.

But I still want to be warned about major amounts of used disk space, what seems to be purpose of this function.

The problem is that I and `apt-get` have different opinion what is major amount of disk space

- for me it would be over 200MB.

And `apt-get`

- well:

  `After this operation, 9805 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y`

Comment: You might want to look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/598836/367990). It gives you a script that probes the download and installation sizes of (a) package(s) and its dependencies and displays them without installing. You can add some lines to it so that it will compare the output with your 200MB value and decide whether to ask (run `sudo apt-get install` normally) or not (run with `-y` switch). Note that apt-get only asks for confirmation depending on whether there are additional dependencies to install, not on the size. See my answer linked above. And don't forget to vote! :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/287357/418028

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with tool itself. The script linked by @ByteCommander would be nice if slightly modified. I think [apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) could use this feature. Consider making a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt) or asking a [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt). Offering a patch is a little more challenging but makes it more likely you and others can get the feature.