# How to force apt to give you a "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]" for every install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I understand that when running the code `sudo apt-get install <packagename>` it will only give me this:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

If that package will [install additional packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/2921/364819). But how do I force `apt` to give me that confirmation dialog every time that I install a package no matter whether or not it will install additional packages as well?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.0.9.2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.0.9.2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.9.2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164464/force-apt-get-to-prompt-yes-no?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make a script that checks first and then launches. For example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Do a test run of the apt-get command, printing the relevant details
sudo apt-get -s install "$@" | 
  perl -ne '$a=1 if /Reading state information/; if($a==1 && /:$/ || /^\s/){print}'

read -p "Do you want to continue? [YN] " response

[[ $response =~ ^[Yy] ]] && sudo apt-get install "$@"
```

If you save that script somewhere in your path, for example as `~/bin/apt-nanny` and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/apt-nanny`), you can use it to install packages (using `nedit` as an example):

```
$ apt-nanny nedit
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 lightdm-gtk-greeter
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmotif-common libmrm4 libuil4 libxm4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmotif-common libmrm4 libuil4 libxm4 nedit
Do you want to continue? [YN]
```

If you enter `y` or `Y`, the script will continue and install the packages.

---

**CAVEATS:**

- The script will show you the same information twice in cases where you would have been asked for confirmation anyway.
- I haven't tested this extensively, there may be cases whjere more/less information than you need will be shown.
- It's ugly and runs `apt-get` twice.