# When will "apt-get install" does not asking for Y or N

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt-get install <whatever>` it returns the choice to Y or N.
Is there any exception to this behavior?

Because recently when I ran similar commands (without `-y` ) it didn't ask for Y or N.
I used  Ctrl + C to interupt the process.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/2920/why-sudo-apt-get-install-xxxx-sometimes-request-confirmation-others-not

Comment: "I used Ctrl + C to interpret the process. " do not do that please. Let it run and use "apt-get purge" or "apt-get remove" to undo it.