# Aptitude not asking for my consent when performing successive tasks

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, aptitude

I am having this weird issue with `aptitude`: when I perform multiple successive tasks, it does not asks for my consent (*i.e.* type `y` or `n` to proceed) every time.

As an example, I was installing `cuetools` and it asked for my consent before proceeding (see the seventh line):

```
user@host:~$ sudo aptitude install cuetools 
[sudo] password for user: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuetools flac{a} python-mutagen{a} vorbis-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 398 kB of archives. After unpacking 1.628 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Get: 1 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 flac i386 1.3.1-4 [147 kB]
Get: 2 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 python-mutagen all 1.31-1ubuntu1 [102 kB]                                        
Get: 3 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 vorbis-tools i386 1.4.0-7ubuntu1 [105 kB]                                        
Get: 4 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 cuetools i386 1.4.0-2 [43,2 kB]                                                  
Fetched 398 kB in 24s (16,4 kB/s)                                                                                                                
Selecting previously unselected package flac.
(Reading database ... 209720 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/flac_1.3.1-4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking flac (1.3.1-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-mutagen.
Preparing to unpack .../python-mutagen_1.31-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-mutagen (1.31-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vorbis-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../vorbis-tools_1.4.0-7ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking vorbis-tools (1.4.0-7ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cuetools.
Preparing to unpack .../cuetools_1.4.0-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking cuetools (1.4.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up flac (1.3.1-4) ...
Setting up python-mutagen (1.31-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up vorbis-tools (1.4.0-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuetools (1.4.0-2) ...
```

Almost immediately after that I installed `shntool` and `wavpack` but the system installed them without asking for my consent:

```
user@host:~$ sudo aptitude install shntool 
[sudo] password for user: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  shntool 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 71,8 kB of archives. After unpacking 283 kB will be used.
Get: 1 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 shntool i386 3.0.10-1 [71,8 kB]
Fetched 71,8 kB in 1s (59,9 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package shntool.
(Reading database ... 209823 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shntool_3.0.10-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking shntool (3.0.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up shntool (3.0.10-1) ...

user@host:~$ sudo aptitude install wavpack 
[sudo] password for user: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wavpack 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 57,2 kB of archives. After unpacking 165 kB will be used.
Get: 1 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 wavpack i386 4.75.2-2 [57,2 kB]
Fetched 57,2 kB in 1s (43,6 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package wavpack.
(Reading database ... 209857 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wavpack_4.75.2-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking wavpack (4.75.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up wavpack (4.75.2-2) ...
```

So my question is: why is `aptitude` not asking for my consent every time and how can I make it do it?

---

**NOTE:**

Asking this question elsewhere I got the suggestion to make `sudo` ask for my password every time I invoke it. I did it (as can be seen in the logs) but clearly this is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/287348/why-does-apt-get-sometimes-asks-for-confirmation/287357#287357.

Answer (score 2):

[As with `apt-get`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2920/why-sudo-apt-get-install-xxxx-sometimes-request-confirmation-others-not), `aptitude` will only ask for confirmation if it's going to install additional packages (like dependencies). You can make it always prompt for a single run with the `-P` option:

```
$ sudo aptitude -P install wavpack
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  wavpack
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/68.3 kB of archives. After unpacking 160 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
```

Or you can make it always prompt on every run by executing:

```
echo 'Aptitude::CmdLine::Always-Prompt "true";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05aptitude
```

These options are `aptitude` specific, however; they will not work with `apt` or `apt-get`.